# Return data format like default DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have spent too much time trying to figure out how to format a queryset and have drf return it like how its default GET request looks like.

ex. get request looks like, a list of objects:

```
[{
        "id": 1093,
        "manytomanyrelation": [
            108793,
            108792,
            108791
        ],
        "count": 3,
},
{
        "id": 1092,
        "manytomanyrelation": [
            108793,
        ],
        "count": 5,
}]
```

My post request which needs to return a list of objects just like above:
code:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
def mymethod(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = MyModel.objects.filter(**params)
    response = serializers.serialize('json', list(data))
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

But this returns objects with pk, model, fields format:

```
[{
    fields:{
            "manytomanyrelation": [
                108793,
                108792,
                108791
            ],
            "count": 3,
    }
    model: "app.mymodel"
    pk: 1093
},
{
    fields:{
            "manytomanyrelation": [
                108793,
            ],
            "count": 5,
    }
    model: "app.mymodel"
    pk: 1092
}]
```

I stripped some fields and names so sorry if there something inconsistent in the data.

Is there any way to format the response object to look like the drf default GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serializers.serialize formats the object in this pk,fields format.
The issue was I needed to use self.get_serializers to get the proper serializer class

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize you Model (`MyModel`), where you can specify how the object in the response will look like.

Check the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)